# How to use mv to move a file between two partitions

Tags: mount, permissions, sshfs, mv

I have two partitions of an external drive mounted on computer A. A's "media" folder is then mounted using `sshfs` on computer B. On B I can move files between the two partitions in the file manager. I can also use the `cp` command to copy files between the two, but the `mv` command gives me "Permission denied". None of the partitions are owned by root.

Comment: Do you authenticate to access A from B?

Comment: Yes, using a key file.